# TCP connection not working properly when using iPhone as hotspot

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets, tcp, hotspot

I'm developing an application for iOS which is connecting through TCP sockets to a server aplication run on Android. In order to find the IP of the 2nd device I use a UDP request and receive the IP of the server.

It's working well all the time when I'm connecting them to Wi-Fi network or when I use the Android device as a hotspot to the iPhone. But if I want to make the iOS device a personal hotspot, I can't reach connection between the two devices and the app is useless in this regime. Is it possible to connect the devices then and is the algorithm the problem? I would be glad to hear if someone has ever had a similar problem and knows the solution.

Comment: Could it be because the personal hotspot introduces Network Address Translation?